# Child form follow main form

Tags: .net, winforms

How to make the child form follow main form.

for example: open a winform [.net2], winform opens form, form follows the mainform if mainform is moving.

[image]

Comment: Does it really have to be 2 forms? What are you trying to do?

Comment: He is probably trying to do something similar to those tool windows in Paint.NET.

Comment: its it actually possible to do so? when moving the location of the mainform, childforum should follow and keep the distance.

Comment: You'll have to write code to do this. What technology are you using—WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `LocationChanged` event from the MainForm to always set the location of the ChildForm.

Working example:

```
Form childForm = new Form();

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);

  childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
  childForm.Width = this.Width;
  childForm.Height = 96;
  childForm.Location = new Point(this.Left, this.Bottom);
  childForm.Show();
}

protected override void OnLocationChanged(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLocationChanged(e);

  if (childForm != null) {
    childForm.Location = new Point(this.Left, this.Bottom);
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty important that you do this in the OnLoad method, the posted code will only work consistently on your dev machine.  Only in OnLoad is the actual size of the main form known with user preferences and form scaling applied.

Answer (score 0):

Superficially simple answer is just to add handlers for when Mainform is moved or resized and then set childform Location and size accordingly.

However do you say want to stop main form being moved such that childform end up off screen.
Can child form be moved independantly.
What about minimise and maximise?

Might you want other arrangements, nore than one child, left and right, child form above main form...

Be worth writing a layout class, and shoving all this stuff off to it.

Comment: mainform and subform both have static size. and there are no min nor maximise.